# Adding a status column and having different statuses depending on a different column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is an example of my 'Audit_Transactions' table at the moment:

[image]

This is my main table in my database .. I have another table in the database called 'Audit_Evaluation' :

[image]

If the EvaluationResult column on the second picture is 1 then its been evaluated and shows on a Datagrid in my application, whereas if it shows as 0 then its not been Evaluated.

I need to add a status column to my first picture which I have done and i need 3 statuses, Unallocated, Allocated also Evaluated.

Here's the problem, My evaluationID is a bit (0,1) meaning I don't have 3 results to look at if you get me?

How would I go about changing this and also how would I set these statuses depending on the results?

EDIT - Using SQL.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQL Sorry edited post.

Comment: `SQL` is ***not*** a DBMS, it's a *query* language.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you mean your EvaluationResult is a bit. You can modify the datatype of that column to accommodate multiple values (like numeric datatype). For this you can check here: [SQL ALTER TABLE Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp).

Then you can use a trigger that, after an insert or an update on Audit_Evaluation, will update the corresponding row in Audit_Transactions. A quick search on google returned an introductory article about triggers in SQLServer: [Triggers -- Sql Server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25600/Triggers-Sql-Server)

I think you should study a bit of SQL before to apply possible pre-cooked solutions that other users of SO can provide to you.